# How can I modify datatables for subtables?

Tags: html, datatables

I have a table where the columns S No., Name and Contact Number.

There is a '+' button beside teacher name, when we click on the + button some more rows are shown below this teacher (These rows contains detail of student which he/she teaches).

After applying datatable to the table, if I click on + button beside teacher's name it shows his students name but they are randomly organised as they are also getting sorted by the datatable.

What I want is teachers names should be shown in sorted manner and when I click on + button it should show their students exactly in next rows.
How can I modify the script for the same?

Here's my **Code** for toggling

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "order": [
            [1, "asc"]
        ]
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tgl").click(function() {
        $(".students").toggle();
    });
});
```

**JSfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/Bihari12/oe3p9nbm/2/

I'm Using the following code for toggling The code for toggling 
[image]

When I click on the button next to "Vineet" it shows their students Tonny  and Rahul. But these are shown at random positions as these are sorted by datatables.
I just want to show them in the next row of "Vineet".

Comment: can you show your code?.

Comment: @Dipak Thoke Updated In Question.